# AWS getting credentials from Cognito Identity Pool using user pool JWT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to build a function in lambda that would get the user’s AWS credentials (in order to make an Authorization signature to request S3 resources.

`event.headers.Authorization` is a JWT from Cognito user pool sign in and is used in a lot of other functions and works properly.

Below in the code snippet I tried to use to get the credentials

EDIT: I can confirm that the JWT used in the Authorization header here is an ID token

```
    console.log(event.headers.Authorization)
                AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                    IdentityPoolId: 'ap-northeast-2:443c5880-d302-4dcf-8cea-b1835723cdb4',
                    Logins: {
                        'cognito-idp.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-2_onyCNlZBF': event.headers.Authorization
                    }
                });
                console.log(AWS.config.credentials)
```

Below is the response , the access key and session token is missing

```
CognitoIdentityCredentials {
  expired: true,
  expireTime: null,
  refreshCallbacks: [],
  accessKeyId: undefined,
  sessionToken: undefined,
  params: {
    IdentityPoolId: 'ap-northeast-2:443c5880-d302-4dcf-8cea-b1835723cdb4',
    Logins: {
      'cognito-idp.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-2_onyCNlZBF': 'eyJraWQiOiJJVlpiNkZTUUJudWlnZHRZMldrMkZuQTNXaHQ1dVNpTVhFdlVQaE0xSFdzPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiI3MDdhNjQ0Ny04NzZiLTRlNDItYjc1OS0zNWIxZmI3YTQ2NzciLCJhdWQiOiIycjJjZ2V2dGkyOW9mZzg3bWJuaTZwazdwdSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJldmVudF9pZCI6ImUyNjM2ZDdkLTgzZTUtNDgwNC04ZmJjLTQwN2IyNTU3NmU3YyIsInRva2VuX3VzZSI6ImlkIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTkxMDY3NzI1LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvY29nbml0by1pZHAuYXAtbm9ydGhlYXN0LTIuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbVwvYXAtbm9ydGhlYXN0LTJfb255Q05sWkJGIiwiY29nbml0bzp1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFsZXgiLCJleHAiOjE1OTEwNzEzMjYsImlhdCI6MTU5MTA2NzcyNiwiZW1haWwiOiJhbGV4Lnd0aG9AZ21haWwuY29tIn0.7fPwMZEVgOIroiO32bOxAyWxaBkFQco772j9i8m3LNpMx2NxW0UzlE-8J4bp6T0np6HK0MaPgg9BY0qfKjTFYWuMzf6mA7ah6aW30U7yosOyzsuK1CWz8Ksa_-QneLtMcbFVxyAZ8jWqK-TQXhS0IctPK4zehuugvymfjzC11GPcZ9sWoS3X-u2jSebUSta1pce_EEgL3rsL3XUZIxnZZiAqYw-vmFnz64ATqYa13ggsSoGYsATU5JTmO_tTut3xsitp_s7m5jCkqouzj11XvuBZDITXiZPN1ZY62jQ6Mhk9Kin1558DNxhgb2lJTcwUSr6577bVwWJsimp22ca0gw'
    }
  },
  data: null,
  _identityId: null,
  _clientConfig: {}
}
```